# NEXTJS13 : Can i use javascript files(in pages-directory) or is it strictly recommended to use only typescript files in the latest version?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, web-development-server

The previous versions of nextJS had JS files in their app directory whereas the latest version have typescript files instead.Can I start the development using javascript now?

I am trying to build an app using nextJS,and im only familiar with JS but not with TS.I'm not sure if it is possible to avoid typescript completely while building the app on nextJS 13.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Javascript in latest version of Nextjs. Setup new project using below command and it will ask you different questions. Just answer NO to Typescript.

```
npx create-next-app@latest
```